# Android: Right-To-Left or Left-To-Right layout design based on location

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, localization

I'd like to have different `layout` design based on `location`. actually I know we can have different layout based on mobile device size.

As you know Android has very good feature that you can inflate all texts in your application based on location which is called [Localization](https://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/localization-checklist.html?utm_source=udacity&utm_medium=course&utm_campaign=android_basics#manage-strings).

I am looking for a kind of similar feature that force my android app to inflate suitable layout design based on location.

In Persian and Arabic, the orientation of components is better to be `Right-To-Left`, although it is possible by designing exact wanted layout, but i don't know how to make it international because regardless of size, I need to have different layout design orientation based on user location, like USA, Germany, Iran and etc.

Is there any easy and automatic way to change layout orientation from `left-to-right` to `right-to-left` based on user location? I've checked similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22752565/android-app-ui-orientation-in-right-to-left-languages-arabic-hebrew-and-persi) in stackoverflow, but that solution is not my aim and goal.

thank you :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `layout` subfolders to provide different layouts depending on language direction. (`layout-ldrtl`).

Also You can provide different layouts depending on language (`layout-ar` in Your case).

In that case layouts that contained in simple `layout` folder will be defaults.

More info You can find in [developer site](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)

Comment: it's very good answer, but unfortunately it just works on API 17 or higher

Answer (score 1):

ofcurse, it has some ways to make it works.

**RTL Layouts directory(the the right way)**

> The layout direction of your application. ldrtl means
>   "layout-direction-right-to-left". ldltr means
>   "layout-direction-left-to-right" and is the default implicit value.
>
> This can apply to any resource such as layouts, drawables, or values.
>
> For example, if you want to provide some specific layout for the
>   Arabic language and some generic layout for any other "right-to-left"
>   language (like Persian or Hebrew) then you would have:
>
> res/
>       layout/
>           main.xml  (Default layout)
>       layout-ar/
>           main.xml  (Specific layout for Arabic)
>       layout-ldrtl/
>           main.xml  (Any "right-to-left" language, except
>                     for Arabic, because the "ar" language qualifier
>                     has a higher precedence.) Note: To enable right-to-left layout features for your app, you must set supportsRtl
>   to "true" and set targetSdkVersion to 17 or higher.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

**Run time**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23203698

Answer (score 0):

Set `LAYOUT_DIRECTION="rtl"`
and set `GRAVITY="start"`